# Facebook Graph Api test app installation

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-test-users

I'm developing an app that makes usage of the FB graph api, more specifically the groups end point. With the new regulations over the permissions in April + the review process, I decided to use the "test app" process to test the implementation, but I can't find a way of how to install my test app on the groups created on my test users generated for my app. Is there any standard process for that or I need to publish my production app in order to test the installation in a group?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: not yet, waiting on facebook support team too

Comment: @dakairus can you please post the link for the support ticket you opened?